What determines build order in Astro?
I am building a website using Astro in which i share database data in many different pages. I have a members.json.ts file in the project root from which i then fetch data as such:
let response = await fetch(`${Astro.url.origin}/members.json`)
let data: any = await response.json();

I can't seem to find anything about build order in the Astro documentation. Is there any way i can ensure that my members.json.ts file has finished building when i fetch the data from each page? Or is there any other preferred way of doing this?

This is considered an anti-pattern. Instead of passing data through requests, you can abstract your members.json.ts API into a separate module and export a function (or whatever you want) for use inside other files, something like this:
Create a common module:
/src/members.ts
export function getMembers() {
  return { // member data }
}

Using the module:
/src/pages/members.json.ts
import { getMembers } from '../../members'

export async function GET() {
  return new Response(JSON.stringify(getMembers()))
}

/src/pages/index.astro
---
import { getMembers } from '../members'

const data = getMembers()
---


Ended up doing precisely this. Was wondering how this affects build times though? I have ended up needing to call my function to fetch data 18 times, instead of doing it three times (one for each table) and sorting it out on my server which i initially wanted to. I can definetly decrease the amount of fetches by doing some abstractions but maybe Astro does some under the hood stuff to optimize?

You can cache the value inside a variable like an object. When you get your data, check the cache first and use that, if the cache doesn't exist add the data to the cache for the next call
